# stream writer is not writing to JSON file in webapi

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, streamwriter

Im trying to write data in a JSON file using webapi but stream writer is not writing data to the file.

JSON File :

```
{
"Students": [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ravi",
  "department": "IT"
  },

 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Raj",
  "department": "hr"
  },
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "avi",
  "department": "it"
 },
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "rome",
  "department": "HR"
 },
 {
  "id":5,
  "name": "virat",
  "department": "HR"
 },
 {
  "id":6 ,
  "name": "Tushar",
  "department": "RM"
 }
]
}
```

Class

```
     public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }
}

    public class Students
{
    public List<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

Api controller: [HttpPost] method for writing data to the json file.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{

  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(Students _Student)
    {        
        using (var fs = new FileStream("C:/Users/tanmay_pawar/source/repos/CRUDAPI/CRUDAPI/people.json", FileMode.Append))
         using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
           sw.WriteLine(_Student);
        }

}
```

The data recieved in  by _Student is not getting added to the json file.

Comment: So you are trying to `write` student object which you are geting from `API` into the specific path using `fileStream` is that expected?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  yes i want to write student object to the json file.

Comment: I think you have got the wrong idea. it does not work the way you are expecting. you need to deserialize the json into object array and then add your student object to array and serialize again and write again to json file.

Comment: @CodingMytra im new to it not getting how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public IActionResult Add(Students _Student)
{
      if(_Student==null || _Student.students==null)  return null;

    var filePath = @"C:\Users\....\..json";
    var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    
    Students students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Students>(json);
  
    students.students.AddRange(_Student.students);
    
    json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(students);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(Students _Student)
        {
            string jsonresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Student);

            string path = @"C:\c\people.json";

          
            using(var tw=new StreamWriter(path,true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(jsonresult.ToString());
                tw.Close();
            }

            return Ok();
}
```

result:

[image]

[image]

**Update more picture,  add data inside the existing JSON file.**

[image]

Comment: The new data  of _Student  object is getting added outside the JSON.

Comment: {
  "Students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Ravi",
      "department": "IT"
    },

    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raj",
      "department": "hr"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "avi",
      "department": "it"
    }
  ]
}          
{"Id":8,"Name":"alex","Department":"it"}

Comment: i want to add data inside the existing JSON file

Comment: @TanmayPawar        Yes, my demo can add data inside the existing JSON file. See my picture, I add a new name aa into the json file.

Comment: yes but it should add it inside students. With your code it is creating two arrays of students.